# Subroutine returning all 0s

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to return the values from a user defined function, but all that is returned are 0s. I feel like the values I'm assigning to the variables wk1 and wk2 aren't being used in the function.

The goal of the subroutine is to calculate the weekly returns of stocks, given the prices provided in Worksheet "Prices".

I'm not very savvy with VBA so any help is appreciated

Thanks for the help!

```
Public Sub wklyrtn()
Dim wk1, wk2 As Long
Dim row As Long, column As Long
Dim matrix1(2 To 261, 2 To 11) As Integer



Sheets("Prices").Select
Selection.Activate

For row = 2 To 261
    For column = 2 To 11
        wk2 = Cells(row, column).Value
        wk1 = Cells(row + 1, column).Value
        matrix1(row, column) = Rtrn(wk1, wk2)
    Next column
Next row

Sheets("Returns").Select
Selection.Activate

For row = 2 To 261
    For column = 2 To 11
        Cells(row, column) = matrix1(row, column)
    Next column
Next row


End Sub

Public Function Rtrn(wk1, wk2)
Dim delt As Long
Application.Volatile True

delt = wk2 - wk1
Rtrn = delt / wk1

End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps your values are all being truncated to 0 since you declared `matrix` to be `Integer`. Replace `Integer` by `Variant` and see what happens.

Comment: Several errors here. First of all, you cannot declare `Dim wk1, wk2 As Long` it will only declare wk2 as long, you have to do `Dim wk1 as long, wk2 as long`. But this is not why it will fail. Also avoid to use `select`. You probably need to use `set` to refer to an object reference (your worksheet)

Comment: Sorry for incorrectly stating it. I've deleted the comment and post correct info here:
John's suggestion will get your code working. If an array is declared as some type (for example integer), all values going to this array must have the same type. By declaring it as Variant all types of values are properly transferred to this array. Never declare anything as Integer, if needed use Long. On 32 and 64 bit systems Integer is converted to Long anyway, so there is no performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Not sure what you are trying to do with the `Matrix`. But this will give you the values you need. You need to refer to an object (your worksheets) instead of using `select` (always avoid that in general and try to refer to an object instead by using `set`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub wklyrtn()
Dim wk1 As Long, wk2 As Long
Dim row As Long, column As Long
Dim matrix1(2 To 261, 2 To 11) As variant
Dim wks As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices")

With wks
For row = 2 To 261
    For column = 2 To 11
        wk2 = wks.Cells(row, column).Value
        wk1 = wks.Cells(row + 1, column).Value
        matrix1(row, column) = Rtrn(wk1, wk2)
    Next column
Next row
End With

Set wks2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Returns")

With wks2
For row = 2 To 261
    For column = 2 To 11
        wks2.Cells(row, column) = matrix1(row, column)
    Next column
Next row
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Get_Price_Index_Var()
Dim lRow As Long, bCol As Byte              'Avoid naming varaibles same as VBA objects, properties, etc
Dim vResults(2 To 261, 2 To 11) As Variant  'Using variant datatype gives flexibility to hold the result of the operations perform
Dim aResults As Variant                     'Used get resulting array to be enter in Returns Worksheet
Dim vVal1 As Variant, vVal2 As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices")
        For lRow = 2 To 261
            For bCol = 2 To 11
                vVal1 = .Cells(lRow, bCol).Value
                vVal2 = .Cells(1 + lRow, bCol).Value
                vResults(lRow, bCol) = fReturns(vVal1, vVal2)
    Next: Next: End With
    aResults = WorksheetFunction.Index(vResults, 0, 0)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Returns")
        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(aResults), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults
    End With

    End Sub


Public Function fReturns(vVal1 As Variant, vVal2 As Variant) As Variant
    fReturns = (vVal2 - vVal1) / vVal1
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

other than working with Variant variables (as you've already been told), you can take advantage of using arrays to both speed up macro execution and shorten down your code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub wklyrtn()
    Const ROWMIN As Long = 2
    Const ROWMAX As Long = 261
    Const COLMIN As Long = 2
    Const COLMAX As Long = 11

    Dim row As Long, column As Long
    Dim data As Variant, matrix1 As Variant

    With Sheets("Prices")
        data = .Range(.Cells(ROWMIN, COLMIN), .Cells(ROWMAX + 1, COLMAX)).Value '<--| read all needed values into 'data' array (it needs one row more at the bottom)
    End With

    ReDim matrix1(1 To ROWMAX - ROWMIN + 1, 1 To COLMAX - COLMIN + 1) As Double '<--| size  returned valuse array accordingly to chosen rows and column indexes ranges
    For row = 1 To ROWMAX - ROWMIN + 1
        For column = 1 To COLMAX - COLMIN + 1
            matrix1(row, column) = Rtrn(data(row + 1, column), data(row, column)) '<-- store returned values into 'matrix1' array
        Next column
    Next row

    Sheets("Returns").Cells(2, 2).Resize(ROWMAX - ROWMIN + 1, COLMAX - COLMIN + 1 + 1).Value = matrix1 '<--| write returned values from 'matrix1' array into cells
End Sub

Public Function Rtrn(wk1, wk2)
    Dim delt As Long
    Application.Volatile True

    delt = wk2 - wk1
    Rtrn = delt / wk1
End Function
```